# Mantine Modal not showing

Tags: css, reactjs, vite, mantine

I created a React App using Vite and installed `Mantine v6.0.0`. When I call the following function to open a Mantine modal the view dims however the modal is not visible.

```
const openModal = () => modals.openConfirmModal({
    title: 'Please confirm your action',
    children: (
      <Text size="sm">
        This action is so important that you are required to confirm it with a modal. Please click
        one of these buttons to proceed.
      </Text>
    ),
    labels: { confirm: 'Confirm', cancel: 'Cancel' },
    onCancel: () => console.log('Cancel'),
    onConfirm: () => console.log('Confirmed'),
  });
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Turns out that the vite react template imported some default styling (`index.css`) which prevented the modal from showing properly. As soon as I removed the css import which included the following css property the modal worked fine.

```css
body {
  display: flex
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for coming back and updating this, been stuck for about 2 hours!